# How to differentiate docker system logs from docker container logs?

Tags: docker, logging, daemon

Everything I saw about the docker daemon logs is that they can be found under `journalctl -u docker` in case of `systemd` presence.

Recently my docker (v.1.13.1) containers hung up. `sudo journalctl -u docker` only gives me container logs that generated by my applications. I see no docker daemon output there. Docker logging driver is `journald`. I also enabled debug output in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. Nothing changed.

So, how to see docker daemon system logs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using docker 17.09.0-ce, but I hope that with my suggestions you could activate them.

1. First of all, shutdown dockerd daemon.
2. Second, edit dockerd configuration file and activate loglevel.

> In my case, docker config file is in **/etc/init/docker.conf**

There, you'll finde something like that:

```
script
        # modify these in /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB (/etc/default/docker)
        DOCKERD=/usr/bin/dockerd
        DOCKER_OPTS=
        if [ -f /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB ]; then
                . /etc/default/$UPSTART_JOB
        fi
        exec "$DOCKERD" $DOCKER_OPTS --raw-logs
end script
```

Look at exec line, where is specified **--raw-logs**. At this line you should add **--log-level debug**, because default is info, as you can see in dockerd help:

```
dockerd --help | grep log-level
 -l, --log-level string                        Set the logging level ("debug"|"info"|"warn"|"error"|"fatal") (default "info")
```

3. Finally, restart docker daemon and check logs with journalctl.

   `sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart`
4. Check logs as you told before.

   `sudo journalctl -u docker`